# How to detect slow internet connection in android app

Tags: android, signal-strength, android-connectivitymanager

I want to detect if a phone has a slow internet connection or high-speed internet.

Now they have deprecated `NetworkInfo` and suggesting that we should use `ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities`  using this I am able to get the signal strength but not able to figure out how to use integer value returned by `networkCapabilities.getSignalStrength()`

It is returning an Integer value I am getting these values (-39, -71, -31).
My question is how should we define that signal strength is good/poor.

Here is my code to get Signal Strength:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Network activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetwork();
        NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork);
        int signalStrength = networkCapabilities.getSignalStrength();
```

Answer (score 6):

First this is a directive approach rather than being a direct answer to the question.

```
int signalStrength = networkCapabilities.getSignalStrength();
```

Doc:

> This is a signed integer, with higher values indicating a stronger signal. The exact units are bearer-dependent. For example, Wi-Fi uses the same RSSI units reported by wifi code.

This means that `signalStrength` holds a value that is relevant to the signal bearer; for instance if the bearer is WiFi, then the `signalStrength` will reflect the same WiFi RSSI units.

> RSSI, or “Received Signal Strength Indicator,” is a measurement of how well your device can hear a signal from an access point or router. It’s a value that is useful for determining if you have enough signal to get a good wireless connection.

So, you need to map those units to some quality gauge to know whether the signal is weak/strong. This is communication/signal dependent rather than a programming point of view... [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797920/how-to-convert-wifi-signal-strength-from-quality-percent-to-rssi-dbm) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399364/get-signal-strength-of-wifi-and-mobile-data) may help you for that in case of WiFi bearer.

But you need to customize this quality level for other types of signal bearers the same-wise according to their RSSI units.

**GSM signal** for instance you may use [CellSignalStrengthGsm](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthGsm) which has [`getRssi()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthGsm#getRssi())

[`CellSignalStrengthLte`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte) is for **LTE** and so on.

You may also get the level of signal strength from the android.telephony API's [`SignalStrength`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength) class... there is a [`getLevel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength#getLevel()) method which returns an integer from 0 to 4 representing the general signal quality. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711159/signalstrength-getsignalstrength-getlevel) you can find a listener to that.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your answer let me follow this and will update you